# custom action on install only

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I have set a custom action to be triggered on installation only

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
   <Custom Action="caPopulateDatabase" Before="InstallFiles">NOT INSTALLED AND NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

For some reason, that custom action triggered during uninstall as well.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following installed:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
   <Custom Action="caPopulateDatabase" Before="InstallFiles">NOT Installed</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Windows Installer is case sensitive. Also, based on your question, you don't need to block when being removed during major upgrade so I removed the `NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE`.